# Exposed filter AJAX error

Tags: 7, ajax, views

I have put an exposed filter on my page, which is an auto-submit textbox without any submit button. When I put the focus on this textbox and **refresh** the page with no value inside the textbox, the page gives me an error which is caused by emptiness of the textbox.

```
**Error:**
An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally.
Debugging information follows.
Path: /************/views/ajax
StatusText: 
ResponseText: 
ReadyState: 4
```

What is your solution for it?

Answer (score 2):

When you give the focus to your field, it triggers an ajax call to the server. If you reload the page right away, it breaks the ajax call and throw this error in an alert.

This only happens as you reload the page during an ajax call. As far as i know you can't do anything about it, unless you modify the core I guess - which is "unclean".

You could use the classes added in css to display a loader while there is an ajax call to the server, and let the user know the page is working on something.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to clive's comment I actually got rid of this alert by overriding Drupal's `Drupal.ajax.prototype.error` function.

In a js file, you can add :

```
Drupal.ajax.prototype.error = function (response, uri) {
  // Remove the progress element.
  if (this.progress.element) {
    $(this.progress.element).remove();
  }
  if (this.progress.object) {
    this.progress.object.stopMonitoring();
  }
  // Undo hide.
  $(this.wrapper).show();
  // Re-enable the element.
  $(this.element).removeClass('progress-disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
  // Reattach behaviors, if they were detached in beforeSerialize().
  if (this.form) {
    var settings = response.settings || this.settings || Drupal.settings;
    Drupal.attachBehaviors(this.form, settings);
  }
};
```

This is a copy of the original error handler callback without the alert() function. This will remove your message, but will also hide any error message returned by Drupal's Ajax.

Comment: The message comes from `Drupal.ajax.prototype.error`, but it's invoked from `Drupal.ajax` itself. The latter would need to be monkey patched to change that behaviour, no need to edit anything in core as such

Comment: Thanks for your wise comment! I just tested, and your right, no need to modify the code. I updated my answer.